# Convert utc date to local date using momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a `DateTime` string like `2/24/2017 17:00:00` which comes from a web service. The time is `UTC` time. Now i want to convert it to user's local time and display it in browser. And i'm using `Moment.js`.

I've tried:

```
var utcTime= moment('2/24/2017 17:00:00' + " +0000", "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss Z");

var localTime = utcTime.add(new Date().getTimezoneOffset().toString(), 'm').toDate();
```

It will work but somehow looks strange. Am i missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
moment.utc('2/24/2017 17:00:00', "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss").local().format('lll');
```

Reference: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Agreed. My only suggestion would be to specify the format when instantiating the moment object to avoid any ambiguities. For instance: moment.utc('2/24/2017 17:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss').local().format('lll');

Comment: @Wissam thanks, you are right, added the format in answer :)